# My form validation is not working

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

I'm try to validate email and names and what not. I'm using a [jquery plugin](http://www.benjaminkeen.com/open-source-projects/smaller-projects/really-simple-validation-js/really-simple-validation-jquery-plugin/#demo_forms) to try and validate my form. But the thing is that the form does not even go to the javascript, it seems to just reset. Could someone help me?

Here's the html:

```
<form action method="post" id="register" name="register" class="well form-horizontal">
<label>Username:</label><input type="text" name="username" id="username" />
<label>Email:</label><input type="text" name="email" id="email" />
<label>Password:</label><input type="password" name="password1" id="password1" />
<label>Repeat Password</label><input type="password" name="password2" id="password2" />
<input type="submit" class="btn" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Here's my javascript (it's from the jquery plugin):

```
function myOnComplete () {
        alert("does this even work?");
        return false;
    }

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#register").RSV({
          onCompleteHandler: myOnComplete,
                rules: [
                        "required,name,Please enter a username.",
                        "required,email,Please enter your email address.",
                        "valid_email,email,Please enter a valid email address.",
                        "required,password1,Please enter a password.",
                        "custom_alpha,password1,xxxDDD,The first three characters must be numbers, the last three must be letters."
                ]
        });
        return true;
    });
```

Comment: Whatever the answers, please remember to also validate the information on the server. Javascript is easy to tamper with.

Comment: @Erty right I'm definitely validating server-side.

Comment: Did you include <script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.rsv-X.Y.Z.min.js"></script> references?

Comment: Ya. And the jquery is reference before the rsv script.

Comment: Are you seeing Console errors either on page load or on submit press? Can you get any JavaScript to run -- even an irrelevant color-change-on-button-press? Is the form's JavaScript submit event firing? Can you post more complete code on JSFiddle?

Comment: i am getting an error in the plugin script. It says that object r has no method "focus".

Comment: answering one of the questions, I am getting an error in the plugin script. It says that object r has no method "focus".